# Dynamic Buckets for Time in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset of counts and actual time. I would like to show a line graph of counts per time, but with the time field bucketed in either 15, 30, or 60 minute intervals chosen by a slicer. I have created a measure on the dataset that reads the slicer and returns the time bucket I would like to display, but Power BI won't let that measure be used as the X Axis in the visual. I've been reading every article that comes close to this use case, but am coming up blank on being able to adapt something to work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

Below is the code for the measure I'm using

```
Time =
TIME(
    HOUR(MIN(Stops[Actual Time])),
    FLOOR(
        MINUTE(MIN(Stops[Actual Time])),
        MIN(Buckets[Bucket Width])
    ),
    0
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample data table that you're trying to work with?